# Typescript never extends `${infer P}` yield different result than never extends `${infer P}/`

Tags: typescript

```
type a = never extends `${infer P}` ? P : 1 // never
type b = never extends `${infer P}/` ? P : 2 // string
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UB2EBuEBOUIA9gSQBMBnKAAwBIBvASyQDNMoAFAXzKgH4WoAuKAIwAoAPQioEgHqchoSFABGCZGia58RUpVoMmbER27M+UAEyjxUzkA)

**never** extends everything, that is why we don't get **1** or **2**

But why `a` is **never** but `b` is **string**, how is that make sense???

I was expecting **never** because `${never}/` is `never`, but **string** ????

how is that possible?

Comment: The answer to this is presumably hidden in the details of the code in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336 , because it's not mentioned in the description and I don't see any existing GitHub issues about it.  I'm *guessing* that both of these involve some sort of inference failure, especially the second example.  In terms of "sense" there's nothing *incorrect* about saying `never extends \`${string}/\`` so it's valid behavior.  But I agree it's not what I'd expect and that `never` would be a more obvious output than `string`.

Comment: You might want to file a new GitHub issue about it (and do so properly, following the rules in the bug template) if you want an authoritative answer.  I might do so if I get a chance but I'm not sure.

Comment: @jcalz issue opened https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently it is a bug https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50215

the behavior of never extends `${infer P}/` is correct and never extends `${infer P}` should follow it

Answer (score 1):

Likely because the string interpolation technically yields a string. For example, `${infer P}/` has a slash at the end which forces the type to be a string. The other interpolation does not, so the type checker infers `never`.